# Reference request for "deep understanding" of generalized linear model theory

Tags: statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling

I'm currently studying in a generalized linear models course and I bought Nelder because I thought it was a "classic" in the field, which it may be, but it is not providing me with what I'm looking for.

Specifically, I'm looking for a first principles exposition into statistical modelling.

This means that the topic of exponential families are not DEFINED, rather, they should be DERIVED.

What resource will provide a deep, first principles, understanding in GLMs and more?